# Suddenly I can't use more than 36% utlization of CPUs in MATLAB. Why?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, windows-10, cpu, parfor

I could use 100% of my CPUs (using parallel computing-`parfor`) but today I can't use more than 36% with same code today. Why? I installed again, delete MATLAB preferences but I have same problem! I have windows 10 with latest updates and didn't have this problem.

[image]

Comment: Probably because of swapping as your memory is quite bloated. But that's just a guess. (If your code has some IO, there is also some potential slow-down if some HDD is somewhat busy)

Comment: @sascha. I opened some programs with MATLAB (photoshop, ...). It is  stuck on 36%. Maybe it is a windows problem.

Comment: What does it look like if you graph each core separately?

Comment: @NathanOliver. same as above graph.